# Google Cloud Storage with Page Speed Insights

Tags: javascript, css, google-cloud-platform, pagespeed, front-end-optimization

I am really finding hard to get the PageSpeed insights value for my home page above 80 for 100.

I am using Google cloud storage and set the metadata of Cache-Control (eg: gsutil -h "Cache-Control:public,max-age=3600" cp -a public-read -r html gs://bucket/html ) but in PageSpeed results i am still seeing

Should Fix:
Leverage browser caching

I do no how to fix the above issue, as I have set the cache-control to all the files.

Also another suggestion is to :

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content - I am only using bootstrap.css, main.css(custom css file), jquery.js , how can I eliminate render-blocking of these scripts or files, I tried to inline css ( but it seems to be complicated for maintenance in long run)

Please help !!

Comment: Need a url of the website to help.  It's usually due to a font or css file being loaded after javascript are loaded.   Use webpagetest.org to see all the requests and the order in which the requests are being made.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments but I should not share the website (as it is company's website and I am trying to optimise it ) I am following the front end optimization techniques, but i do no how to fix render-blocking errors bootstrap.css, main.css ( Do I need to inline all the css in the html instead of href to them) ??

Comment: Without the url there is nothing I can do for you.  I created an app that runs a series of tests.  Pagespeed Insights is the easiest validation to get 100.  It is also the least useful tool.  webpagetest.org will give you the details necessary to determine the problem if you know what to look for.  If you want, post the waterfall from webpagetest and send me a message.

Comment: And no, in lining is not the answer and not recommended.

Comment: thanks !! Misunderstood

Comment: Setting the cache is a server setting.  The meta tag is a last resort kind of thing.  I may conflict with the HTTP response cache which take priority.  Go to the Inspector or Inspect Element "Network Tab" click on the html page and look at the "headers".